# How to work with delete function in sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to work with this **delete function** of my SQLHandler :

```
public void removeProduct(int id) {
        try {
            String a;
            a = Integer.toString(id);
            getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE_INCOME, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] { a });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am using it like this in my **View Activity:**

```
viewHolder.txt_price.setText( Long.toString(_incomelist.get(position).getPrice()).trim());
viewHolder.txt_type.setText(_incomelist.get(position).getType().trim());
viewHolder.txt_date.setText(_incomelist.get(position).getDate().trim());
viewHolder.txt_desc.setText(_incomelist.get(position).getDescription().trim());
viewHolder.txt_pmode.setText(_incomelist.get(position).getPaymode().trim());

final int temp = position;
(convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2))
        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        ViewContact.this);
                alertbox.setCancelable(true);
                alertbox.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete ?");
                alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                try{
                                db.removeProduct(temp);
                                ViewContact.this.onResume();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Deleted..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        });
                alertbox.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(
                                    DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                            }
                        });
                alertbox.show();
            }
        });
```

The **Problem** part is this it is not throwing any type of exception. Please correct me out! **OR** Please tell me how to call this function?

Comment: Why should it throw an exception?

Comment: OK but its also not deleting any thing in my project! @Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't throw an exception, because `delete` doesn't throw exception. Instead, it returns the number of deleted rows. In your case, probably 0.

The issue is that you are using the position in your adapter instead of the actual id.

I assume your code is in an `onItemClick` ? In which case, use the `long id` parameter rather than the position.

Comment: Yes, I am using it in an onItemClick But how to use long id I am not getting it! edit changes for me please..

Comment: the last parameter in the onItemClick method is the id. (or post your complete onItemClick method)

Comment: edited please check out and sorry its onClick method on which i am working

Comment: I meant the whole onItemClick method with its signature (the first line with the parameters, which is where you'll find the id.